# UICollectionView: minimumInteritemSpacing change on cell selection

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

In my collection view I want to scale the collection view cell that is selected. Along with that I also want to maintain same interItemSpacing between cells before the selection and after the selection, including enlarged cell. But if I just scale the cell by setting cell.transform property scaled cell overlaps on the neighbor cell.Other cells should adjust themselves to maintain the space. How do I solve this ?

i.e,

```
  cell -50pix- cell -50pix- cell

  cell -50pix- scaled cell -50pix- cell
```

Comment: If you apply a transform you're just scaling the view itself within the `UICollectionView`. If you want the entire `UICollectionView` to respond to those size changes you will need to update the item's size in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` and reload the item.

Comment: Thank you its working. But itemSize change is not smooth. I cannot animate it

Comment: How are you reloading the UICollectionView?

Comment: [flowlayout invalidate];

Comment: You just want to reload the cell you are updating, using `-reloadItemsAtIndexPath:`

Comment: can u please just elaborate, I have done like this, assign selected indexpath to a variable and call [flowlayout invalidateLayout]; And in sizeForItemAtIndexPath delegate if indexPath is equal to selected indezPath set enlareged size for taht cell.

Comment: Instead of invalidating the layout, just reload the indexPath that has its size  changed. E.g. [collectionView reloadItemAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying a transform, you are just scaling the view up in size. To adjust the size and allow the rest of the UICollectionView to adjust you will need to return a new size in sizeForItemAtIndexPath:

When the item is selected, you should reload that item at that indexPath using:

```
 [collectionView reloadItemAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath]
```

Replace selectedIndexPath with name of your variable storing the selected indexPath.

You don't want to invalidateLayout because you're just changing the appearance of one item.

Comment: This works, But last cell moves down. some 100 pixels down from rest of the cells

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is the best solution,

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        return cell;
    }

    - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        if ([indexPath isEqual:selectedIndexPath]) {
            return CGSizeMake(175, 175);  // return enlarged size if selected cell
        }
        return CGSizeMake(150, 150);
    }
    -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath;   // set selected indexPath
        [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                [collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                }];
    }

    - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0,0, 0);
    }

    - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
        return 20;
    }
    - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
        return 20;
    }
```